# Query with variable inside throws an error in Code Analysis

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, phpstorm

The variable `$extra_query` breaks the logic of the Code Analysis feature and throws an error:

```
 SELECT *, so.`Location` as so_loc
    FROM vw_dispatch
             left join sales_orders so on vw_dispatch.customerOrderNo = so.External_Document_No
             left join customer_data cd on so.Customer_ID = cd.no
    where 1 = 1
      and archived = 0
      and processed = 0 $extra_query
    order by vw_dispatch_id desc
    limit 0,200
```

Should I stop the inspection for error cases like this?
Should I use a different way to inject that variable?

[image]

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57194

Comment: I wonder: if you remove `1 = 1 and archived = 0 and processed = 0` part from the query and move it into the actual `$extra_query` content (so whole WHERE logic is there) -- will it be any better?

Comment: What this row `and processed = 0 $extra_query` must mean? What value you want to have in a variable during execution?

Comment: @LazyOne I tried and it still shows that error:
https://www.screencast.com/t/cSPocVrjSVDQ

Comment: @Akina the value of this variable will add more possible filters to the query.  It's part of the WHERE  logic. My doubt is about how can I integrate these kind of queries in PHPStorm IDE so the Code Analysis understands this better.

Comment: it should be like: $query = "select * from ..." . $extra_query . "order by col desc limit 0,100"; and $extra_query must be declared before $query_prepared.

Comment: Try to move 1st logical operator from the variable to the query pattern, like `... and processed = 0 AND ($extra_query) ...`. The variable itself will contain `1=1 @additional_conditions`.

Comment: @YuriWin I tried your idea and still not working.
https://www.screencast.com/t/gSwjQHb42

Comment: @Akina Your way might be the good one this time.
https://www.screencast.com/t/mRGF0Bk3
the only problem is that the variable $extra_query is created by a method which return many subqueries and it will take a lot of time to refactor. But I assume that is needed. Thanks

Comment: Should I answer myself this question? how can I give credit to @Akina for the answer?

Comment: *Should I answer myself this question?* Why not? *how can I give credit to @Akina for the answer?* I do not pay attention to it.

Comment: @JuanGarcía Yes, please post an answer and mention Akina. The answer will be helpful for other users with a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @Akina has been the closest to solve this issue.

> Try to move 1st logical operator from the variable to the query
> pattern, like ... and processed = 0 AND ($extra_query) .... The
> variable itself will contain 1=1 @additional_conditions.

[akina_solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5WzW.png)